# How can i access client browser DOM from express?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to access a video player object from the client browser DOM, this video player is initialized by videojs so i need the whole javascript object. The server processes the html that will appear on the page.

I've tried ajax, but then i realized you can only use ajax on the client browser.

```
.container
  .wrapper
    video#vid1.video-js.vjs-default-skin(style='width:100%;height:auto; position: relative;' controls='')
      source(src=videoSource type='video/mp4')
script.
  player = videojs('vid1', {
  controls: true,
  posterImage: false,
  textTrackDisplay: false,
  loadingSpinner: false,
  playPause: true,
  controlBar: {
  fullscreenToggle: false,
  progressControl: false,
  remainingTimeDisplay: false
  }
  });
  player.overlay({
  content: '<strong>Default overlay content</strong>',
  overlays: [{
  align: "top",
  content: '!{htmlContent}',
  start: 'play',
  end: 'pause'
  }]
  });
  player.ready(function () {
  this.on('timeupdate', function () {
  console.log(this.currentTime());
  })
  })
```

I would like the client to receive a new definition to player.overlays given by the server

Comment: What do you mean by *whole* JavaScript object? The only thing you can serialize from the client to the server is the data in an object, not any of its functions (at least not in a useful way). What you get on the server side will be a *copy* of the original, and necessarily an incomplete copy at that. You certainly can't get an object on the server side and call one of that object's functions, and have something happen on the client, if that's what you're hoping for.

Comment: I just want to modify the player.overlays obejct, i dont need functions

Comment: You can certainly do a JSON request from the client, and have the server return JSON that contains something like the `{
  content: '<strong>Default overlay content</strong>',
  overlays: [{
  align: "top",
  content: '!{htmlContent}',
  start: 'play',
  end: 'pause'
  }]
  }` that you have above, but then it's the client's job to apply that to the player when the JSON comes back.

Comment: Thats, what i thought on doing, but i was wondering if there was any cooler way